# Clopen subsets of a closed subspace of a spectral space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Set
$K(X) := \{ A\subseteq X\mid A$   is quasi-compact and open $\}.$ A topological space $X$ is called **spectral**,
if it satisfies all of the following conditions:

1) $X$ is quasi-compact and $T_0$.
  2) $K(X)$ is a basis of open subsets
of $X$.
 3) $K(X)$ is closed under finite
intersections.
  4) $X$ is sober, i.e.
every nonempty irreducible closed subset of $X$ has a (necessarily
unique) generic point.

> Let $C$ be a closed subset of a spectral topological space $X$. I am looking for equivalent conditions on $C$ under which if $A$ is a clopen(=Closed+Open) subset of $C$, then there exists a clopen subset $B$ of $X$ such that $A=C\cap B$?